# What's the difference between these two Structs when making Linked Lists?

Tags: c

Just having confusion what is the difference between the two structs. What does the order do to alter the definition? Thanks.

```
// 1 
struct list
{
    struct list* next;
    unsigned long val;
};

// 2
struct list
{
    unsigned long val;
    struct list* next;
};
```

Comment: Generically, changing the order of members can add or remove padding for the purposes of [memory alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4306186/1707353) but if you adhere to accessing members in a standard way, then you shouldn't be too concerned about the order of members.

Comment: They are equivalent. Depending on the size of the elements on your platform there could be a difference in position or presence of padding but they are still equivalent.

Comment: **1** The second is neater in documenting when vertically drawing a list: last field `next` pointing to the next `struct list` below. **2** The first has a pointer field at the 0 offset of the struct. Some processor might have a more optimal instruction for that. **3** The only difference concerns padding of the fields. Pointer and long must be different length and there must be padding. Which is unlikely here.

Comment: I'd put the link _first_--it's easy to find. This might be more obvious with a more complex linked list element (e.g.) `struct list { struct list *next; unsigned long val; long arrcount; int *arrbase; int param[1000]; };`

Answer (score 1):

Functionally, these two structs will work the same way.  They might not be the same size though due to padding.